# Javascript - ContentEditable holds default CSS

Tags: javascript

I have a content editable element, in here you can update and modify HTML, but when i set a element css animation-delay to an empty string, the css keeps a hold of the default value and returns 0s.

Is there any way around this so that i can remove the css property completely if the css property is empty?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle, do you mean something like this: [link](https://jsbin.com/tinecaziwi/edit?html,output) ?

Comment: for example if i did this in jquery $(selector).css('animation-delay', '') in contentediable, then the css will get applied as animation-delay: 0s, where i want it to be empty